# Disable radio button using Closest in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to disable radio button on both sides on clicking of radio button in center using Closest?

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <label for="COMA">
            <p>
                <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="COM" id="COM0"> 
                Yes &nbsp;&nbsp; 
            </p>
        </label>
    </span>

    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <label for="COMA">
            <p>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="No" name="COM" id="COM1"> 
                No &nbsp;&nbsp; 
            </p>
        </label>
    </span>

    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <label for="COMA">
            <p>
                <input type="radio" value="NA" name="COM" id="COM2"> 
                NA &nbsp;&nbsp; 
            </p>
        </label>
    </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

On Click of No, i want to disable YES and NA radio button, but not by using any looping/iterations or disabling on static Name or ID, 
but want Jquery methods closest or siblings to do the same.

How is this possible in JQuery using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hudzg82h/)**

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click',function(){
    $("input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

or just with a single line

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hudzg82h/2/)**

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click',function(){
    $("input:radio").not($(this)).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.
and what if i have case like this now as pure css classes can be used like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/hudzg82h/5/

Comment: Actually, i want closest radio to get disable which is on right and left. I have complex HTML structure (not design by me) on which the given solution is not getting implemented correctly because i have classes arrangements as i am mentioning again in fiddle. So the reason i asked for closest radio only.

Comment: Check **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hudzg82h/6/)**. You might go with other classes like `pure-u-md-1-5` which are there only for children or you can add a separate class to child to differentiate parent and children and if you want to work with closest its very difficult to get in work with the complex structure whatever you are talking, But again am not saying impossible!! Depends on how html is structured..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, basically you take the closest `<div>` and then find all `<input>` of type `radio` but the "No" radio and disable them.

```
$("#COM1").on("click", function() {
    var $no = $(this);
    $no.closest("div").find("input:radio").not($no).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/4459rqtp/